# Which method in lua could I use to most effectively get the hertz frequency of a certain position in a .wav file?

Tags: lua, wav

So I want to be able to convert a .wav file to a json table using lua, which would probably include something like {time="0:39.34",hz=440} or something. I already have all my json libraries but I just need a method to be able to convert a .wav file into something that I could use to convert it into json. If there's already a library that can do this then I need the source code of the library to be able to implement it into my code for a single-file program.

Answer (score 0):

At each point in wav you'll have a full spectrum, not just "the hertz frequency". You'll have to perform a fourier transform on the data, and from many peaks in spectrum select the one you're interested in - be it fundamental or dominant, etc.

There are libs for Fast Fourier Transform out there, like [LuaFFT](https://luarocks.org/modules/h4rm/luafft), but you'd better get more clear picture of what you really need from the WAV. If you're just trying to read [DTMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-tone_multi-frequency_signaling) signal, you don't really need the full scale spectrum analysis.